# Use CSS to position two elements at the same location and make container large enough to hold them

Tags: css, css-position

So I have two (or potentially more) elements that I want to occupy the same space.  They need to fit inside a container element whose size should be automatically made large enough to contain them.  I currently have a couple of possibilities that don't quite work, shown below:

```css
.first {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}

.first > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}

.second > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.third {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}

.third > li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:right; width: 75%">(Attempt 1: note that the two items are not superimposed, but the container is large enough to hold them)</div>
<ul class="first">
  <li>Item number 1</li>
  <li>Item number 2</li>
</ul> 
<br><br>
<div style="float:right; width: 75%">(Attempt 2: note that this time they are superimposed, but no space is allocated in the container for them)</div>
<ul class="second">
  <li>Item number 1</li>
  <li>Item number 2</li>
</ul>
<br><br><br><br>
Edited to add a third attempt:<br>
<ul class="third">
  <li>Item number 1</li>
  <li>Item number 2</li>
</ul>
```

Ideally I'm looking for a pure CSS solution, but it only needs to work on webkit-based browsers (i.e. chrome / safari).

Updated: add a third attempt that gets the two items overlapping, but allocates enough space to hold both of them side by side, which still doesn't really get me where I want to be.

For reference: I don't know the sizes of the items in advance, so can't (for example) size the container to hold the largest and make the rest overlap it.

Comment: Should we assume that all the child elements will be the same size, as in both your examples? Will the children have solid backgrounds, thus hiding their previous siblings?

Comment: No, the child elements are text of unknown length.  They will only be visible at different times and not actually conflict due to animations running on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [`absolute` positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position):

Setting `position: absolute` on all `<li>` elements, then setting `position: relative` on the `.current` (there are many ways to select a dominant `<li>` and using a class is just one of them) `<li>` gives what I think you're after.

We can then set the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) of every `<li>` to `hidden`, and set the `visibility` of `.current` to `visible` to reduce the visual clutter:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em .3em;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
li.current {
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abcdefg</li>
  <li>foo bar baz</li>
  <li>i dunno lol</li>
  <li class="current">42</li>
</ul>
```

This approach is effectively identical to using `display` `none` and `list-item`:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em .3em;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li {
  display: none;
}
li.current {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abcdefg</li>
  <li>foo bar baz</li>
  <li>i dunno lol</li>
  <li class="current">42</li>
</ul>
```

### Or for the container to always be wide enough for the longest string:

Setting the `height` of every `<li>` to [`0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) and giving just the `.current` its [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/initial) `height` back to push the `<ul>`'s [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border) out, we get something like this:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em .3em;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li {
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
li.current {
  height: initial;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abcdefg</li>
  <li>foo bar baz</li>
  <li>i dunno lol</li>
  <li class="current">42</li>
</ul>
```

### Using JavaScript :O

Although the question calls for a CSS solution, where that might be impossible or unreliable, we can [*always rely*](https://blockmetry.com/blog/javascript-disabled) on JS.

In the case that **both** the `width` and `height` of the child `<li>`s may be different, and that the *container* should be both wide **and** high enough for every child, JS provides.

The method below uses [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the `width` and `height` of the `relative`ly rendered `<li>` elements, and sets `position: absolute` on them all as they're read.

The parent `<ul>` then has its `width` and `height` set to the largest `width` and `height`s of the child `<li>`s.

The result is a `<ul>` that's wide and high enough to contain every child `<li>`, but with all the children `position`ed `absolute`ly;

```js
var widths = [], heights = [];
// loop through all the li elements
document.querySelectorAll( "li" ).forEach( function( v ) {
  // get the computed styles for each li element
  var ecs = window.getComputedStyle( v );
  // push the width into the widths array
  widths.push( ecs.width );
  // push the height into the heights array
  heights.push( ecs.height );
  // set position:absolute on this li element
  v.style.position = "absolute";
} );
document.querySelector( "ul" ).setAttribute( "style",
  /* sort the widths array and pop the last (and therefore largest) value
  then apply it to the width of the ul. */
  "width:" + widths.sort().pop() +
  /* sort the heights array and pop the last (and therefore largest) value
  then apply it to the height of the ul. */
  ";height:" + heights.sort().pop()
);
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em .3em;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li {
  visibility: hidden;
}
li.current {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abcdefg<br>1234567</li>
  <li>foo bar baz</li>
  <li>i dunno lol</li>
  <li class="current">42</li>
</ul>
```

### `display: flex` and `visibility: hidden`

I was wondering if `visibility: collapse` might be useful, and found [a CSS-tricks.com article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/visibility/#article-header-id-4) linking to [a csswg.org draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#visibility-collapse) suggesting that `visiblity: collapse` may be used on `<li>`s with `display: flex` to acheive pretty much exactly what you're after.

I couldn't get it to work, and noticed that their own example was not using either `display: flex` or `visibility: collapse`!
They are instead manipulating the `height`s of the children.

Since it is a draft, this may become a useable solution down the road.

I am unfamiliar with the use of *flexboxes* (deep shame) so wouldn't be surprised if a solution using them exists. I just don't (at this time) know it.

Comment: It seems the effect I wanted (to allow the height of the child items to vary and take the height from the *largest* of them) isn't possible, so in the end I used an approach somewhat like this (except artificially inflating the size by putting a dummy item in the list that doesn't actually get displayed but is known to be larger than any reasonable item *should* be...). It seems a shame that there's no way of sizing a stack of overlapping items such that they have the common size of their largest item, but it certainly appears to be the case.

Comment: @Jules - I'm glad to have helped, but was interested to continue trying to find a solution. In short - I didn't; I updated my answer with a JavaScript solution (because JS can often do what CSS can't) and an interesting possibility for the future using `display: flex`. I also adjusted the snippets I already posted to use a class selector instead of `:last-child` for the *visibility* of the dominant/shown `<li>` as it's less presumptuous.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:0; margin:0;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item number 1</li>
  <li>Item number 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This sets the container to the size of the first item, but ignores the size of the second.  As I do not know in advance which item is longer, this doesn't get me anywhere, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Jules ah. i'm trying to picture how you're using this. you mentioned only 1 `li` element will show at a time, right? but if one `li` is 100px tall, and one `li` is 500px, you want to show the 100px `li` with all that extra white space below it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this:

```css
.second > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
  left:0;
}

.second > li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.second > li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="second">
  <li>Item number 1</li>
  <li>Item number 2 greater length</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Jules do you care about the varying heights or the varying widths?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should include your two elements inside a container div that you want to have and write property as:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

And, make your container position property as:

```
position: relative
```